# Find the series solution for the ODE $x^2y''(x)-3y(x) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

> Find the series solution for the ODE  $x^2y''(x)-3y(x) = 0$

I assume $y(x) = \sum{a_nx^n}$ then substitute in the equation and get

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ({a_nn(n-1) - 3a_n)x^n}=0$$

When I equate the coefficients I get $a_i = 0$ for all i

Then I tried to put $y(x) =x^\alpha \sum{a_nx^n}$ but I still can't get a solution.

Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: Notice the pattern: the powers of $x$ in coefficients are the same as the order of derivative. This means $y=x^a$ should work: you have a [Cauchy–Euler equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second attempt should have led you to a solution.  If you try $ y (x)=x^\alpha $, you get $\alpha^2-\alpha-3=0$, i.e. $\alpha=\frac {1\pm\sqrt {13}} 2$. This gives you two linearly independent solutions.

Comment: Thanks!! I think I confused myself when doing the second attemt, since I did get $\alpha = \frac{1\pm \sqrt{13}}{2}$